# YII backend implementation

Tags: php, configuration, yii, directory-structure, yii-modules

I have created frontend-backend structre following http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/33/
so my structure is

```
wwwroot/
    index.php
    backend.php
    assets/
    images/
    js/
    protected/
        config/
            main.php
        components/
        controllers/
        models/
        modules/
        views/
        runtime/
        backend/
            config/
                main.php
            components/
            controllers/
            models/
            modules/
            views/
            runtime/
```

and my backend config is

```
$backend = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$frontend = dirname($backend);
yii::setPathOfAlias('backend',$backend);
return array(
    'basePath' => $frontend,
    'controllerPath' => $backend.'/controllers',
    'viewPath' => $backend.'/views',
...
    'import'=>array(
    'backend.modules.rights.*',
    'backend.modules.rights.components.*',
    'backend.models.*',
    'backend.components.*',
    'application.modules.user.models.*',
    'application.modules.user.components.*',
),...
```

Now I need to access controllers,models and views at backend from frontend
like **backend.php/discussion**
and discussion is at protected/controllers/DiscussionController
which right now only accesable from **index.php/discussion**

One Solution is 
set **'controllerPath'=>$frontend.'/controllers'**
but now i loose backend controllers.
So is there is way that when i call a controller, first it looks in backend controllers and then look in frontend controllers(in case not found in backend controllers)?

Comment: You should be able to do this by defining routes and placing the backend routes first and the main routes after.

Comment: I didn't get it.How will i do this?

Comment: Have a look http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: Ok i got it now.So you are saying that i should redirect my urls.But here is the problem that.If I redirect "backend.ohp/discussion" to "index.php/discussion" then i will again need login(this is how I am developing my web,where frontend and backend logins are different).I had it in mind but this not the solution, I want to access those fronend cotrollers at backend.Anyway thanks for trying.

Comment: One more solution I see is,like I can Use Modules of frontend in backend easily, so either i create a module for common things or create a folder "common" just like "module" folder which will contain whole m,v and c.But this idea fails when i need only perticular module or controller from frontend. So i am eager see a perfect solution.....

Comment: You can take a look into [YiiBoilerplate](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/374/yiiboilerplate-setup-a-professional-project-structure-in-seconds/) it has similar structure.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to keep backend (with secure login) totally separate to front-end, ie: completely different project.  In this way, your backend can be accessed using a hidden sub-domain like hidden-admin.my-domain.com

If you want to share code then, as you've mentioned above, use components or widgets.